# Como tornar um evento de um controle filho acessível em um UserControl (Windows forms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, eventos, usercontrol

Estou criando um UserControl que usa alguns controles como um DataGridView, Buttom e Label. Ele exibe a quantidade de linhas, permite salvar os dados exibidos em uma planilha e diminui o esforço em outras tarefas básicas.

[O controle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGBnK.jpg)

O problema é que quero acessar por exemplo o evento CellMouseDoubleClick na lista de eventos do UserControl sem precisar acessar o objeto filho.

Sei que é possível acessar o evento desta maneira em um form que eu estiver usando o Controle:

```
UserControl.GridViewControlFilho.CellMouseDoubleClick += (obj, e) =>
{
    //aqui abro um formulário proveniente da linha clicada por exemplo
};
```

Mas gostaria que o evento do controle filho conste na lista de eventos do UserControl para ser acessado desta maneira:

[Lista de eventos do DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8o6V.jpg)

Fiz algo semelhante com algumas propriedades:

```
public DataGridViewColumnCollection Columns
{
   get { return Grid.Columns; }
}

public object DataSource
{
   get { return Grid.DataSource; }
   set { Grid.DataSource = value; }
}
```

Desta maneira acesso propriedades do controle filho direto pelo controle pai. Agora como fazer o mesmo com eventos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do seu `UserControl` voce deve criar uma propriedade publica do evento que deseja ser acessado externamente.

```
public event DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler CellMouseDoubleClick;
```

E no evento do `DataGridView` voce faz referencia ao evento que voce deixou publico.

```
private void GridViewControlFilho_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (CellMouseDoubleClick != null)
     {
         CellMouseDoubleClick.Invoke(sender, e);
     }
}
```

Dessa forma, quando voce adicionar o `UserControl` em outro controle, o evento criado estará disponivel.